# What should I say : The novel took the writer 3 months to write . or The novel took the writer 3 months to write it . And Why ??

Tags: prepositions

What should I say : 
The novel took the writer 3 months to write . 
or 
The novel took the writer 3 months to write it .
And Why ??

Comment: The former. Would you say 'The book cost me $3 to buy' or 'The book cost me $3 to buy it'? 'The car took her 2 hours to paint' or 'The car took her 2 hours to paint it'? Look at [Grammar Quizzes](http://www.grammar-quizzes.com/infinitive3a.html) for similar expressions; when for example  'It took me a week to read this book' is expressed in the manner you use, it becomes 'This book took me a week to read.'

Comment: The interesting thing about "It took me thee months to write the novel" (syntactically standard) versus "The novel took me three months to write it" (not syntactically standard) is that the "It" at the beginning of the first sentence doesn't refer to "the book," but instead is used more broadly, indefinitely, and anticipatorily to mean something like "the task I am about to describe." In contrast, the "it" at the end of the second sentence does refer to "the book" and is therefore redundant, since the book has already been clearly identified as the subject of the sentence.

Comment: @SvenYargs Yes, indeed. I did think of that. And that is why "It took me three months to write it", and "It took me three months to write" are both grammatical - the essential difference, as you point out, being that the first "it" has a different sense in each case.

Answer (score 1):

From comments to the question:

- The interesting thing about "It took me thee months to write the novel" (syntactically standard) versus "The novel took me three months to write it" (not syntactically standard) is that the "It" at the beginning of the first sentence doesn't refer to "the book," but instead is used more broadly, indefinitely, and anticipatorily to mean something like "the task I am about to describe." In contrast, the "it" at the end of the second sentence does refer to "the book" and is therefore redundant, since the book has already been clearly identified as the subject of the sentence. – [Sven Yargs](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/145978/what-should-i-say-the-novel-took-the-writer-3-months-to-write-or-the-novel-t#comment295823_145978)
- @SvenYargs Yes, indeed. I did think of that. And that is why "It took me three months to write it", and "It took me three months to write" are both grammatical - the essential difference, as you point out, being that the first "it" has a different sense in each case. – [WS2](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/145978/what-should-i-say-the-novel-took-the-writer-3-months-to-write-or-the-novel-t#comment295824_145978)

Answer (score 0):

I will try to explain it without recourse to diagrams.

The infinitive complement there can be understood to express the idea of *attaining* a state, with intransitive verbs:

> How long does the paint take to dry?

That is, how much time is required for the paint to *become dry*.

and of having a state *conferred* upon it, with transitive verbs:

> The novel took three years to write.

That is, the novel took three years *to become written*.

These constructions with transitive verbs are Janus-faced: the subject attains a state that can only be conferred upon it.

We can complicate things further by referring to the agent of the action, not in the nominative, however, but in an oblique case:

> The novel took *him* three years to write.

The novel demanded of him three years to become written.